# Calculate how many weeks make up 30 weekdays?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

Getting dates accurate is always tricky. I want to know how many weeks it takes to encapsulate 30 **week days**. The start day can be any day of the **week day**. *Weekends CANNOT be counted.*

For example, if I start on **1/11/2017**, then for 30 week days (inclusive of starting date), the end date is **2/21/2017**. That means it takes **7 weeks**.

---

*This is what I've tried:*

Since `datetime.isocalendar()` can be used to determine the week number in the year, my idea is to take something along the lines of:

`datetime.isocalendar(enddate) - datetime.isocalendar(startdate)`.

*But I believe my enddate calculation is wrong so I am getting weird numbers:*

```
import datetime
def doit(month, day):
    startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-%s-%s" % (month,day),"%Y-%m-%d")
    enddate = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=41)    
    print datetime.datetime.isocalendar(enddate)[1] - datetime.datetime.isocalendar(startdate)[1]
```

I do `days=41` because each week has two weekends that we're not counting, so since 30 weekdays is normally 6 weeks, that means 6*2 + 30 = 42 days total. But since we're counting the starting date, we only add  `42-1=41` days.

Why am I getting incorrect numbers? For example, if you input the dates I listed above (`doit(1,11)`), I'll get `6` weeks which is not correct.

Comment: One approach that comes to mind is to use `date.weekday()` - https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday. You can count the number of times that this function returns 0 (Monday) thru 4 (Friday).

Comment: `startdate = datetime.date(2017, int(month), int(day))`

Comment: 2017-1-11 to 2017-2-21 are 6 weeks though, not 7

Answer (score 1):

one approach would be to just simulate walking over each day, except cancelling out multiples of 5 (whole weeks) beforehand

```
def end_by_weekdays(start, weekdays):
    weeks, weekdays = divmod(weekdays, 5)
    days = 0
    startday = start.weekday()
    while weekdays > 0:
        days += 1
        if (startday + days) % 7 < 5:
            weekdays -= 1
    return start + timedelta(days=days + 7*weeks)
```

This outputs the following:

```
>>> end_by_weekdays(date(2017,1,11), 30)
datetime.date(2017, 2, 22)
```

Note that it outputs the 22nd insteaf of your expected date, which was the 21st, because I treated the starting date exclusive. Easy enough to change though if you want to.

You can then use this date to see how many weeks it takes

```
>>> start = date(2017,1,11)
>>> (end_by_weekdays(start, 30) - start).days / 7
6.0
```

or have `end_by_weekdays()` return the number of days directly to avoid this back-and-forth.

*Note*: I used Python 3 in my code. So that last example will do an integer division on Python 2 and just output `6`

Answer (score 0):

```
print datetime.datetime.isocalendar(enddate)[1] - datetime.datetime.isocalendar(startdate)[1]
```

This statement gives you correct answers if the weekday is Monday! You should think a little bit different considering this condition **The start day can be any day of the week day.**